# Five-minute breaks part of speech

Tags: word-choice

What are such words as "five-minute breaks" called?

"There are five-minute breaks after each lesson."

Answer (score 4):

"Breaks" is a noun (in its plural form)  It is modified by the phrase "five-minute" which is formed from a numeral and a special type of noun: a unit.

The whole phrase is a noun phrase. This noun phrase is the complement in the "There are ..." clause